# If n is positive integer, prove that the prime factorization of $2^{2n}\times 3^n - 1$ contains $11$ as one of the prime factors

Tags: divisibility, prime-factorization

I have: $2^{2n} \cdot 3^{n} - 1 = (2^2 \cdot 3)^n - 1 = 12^n - 1$.
 I know every positive integer is a product of primes, so that,

$$12^n - 1 = p_1 \cdot p_2 \cdot \dots \cdot p_r. $$ 
Also, any idea how to use math notation on this website?

Comment: $$12^n-1=(12-1)(12^{n-1}+12^{n-2}+\cdots+12+1)$$

Comment: I have tried to format your post - take a look at my edits for further reference - and check whether it is what you meant.

Comment: There is a well know result should learn:  $(x^n - y^n) = (x - y)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}y + x^{n-3}y^2 + .... + xy^{n-2} + y^{n-1})$  [try working that out on paper... it's kind of fun.]  So this means $(a -1)$ always divides $(a^n - 1)$.  (because $(a^n - 1)= (a -1)(a^{n-1} +..... + a + 1)$).  So 11 = (12 - 1)|(12^n - 1).  [Ain't that a kick in the pants?]

Answer (score 5):

We have to prove $11|12^n-1$. This follows easily from $$12^n\equiv 1^n=1\ (\ mod\ 11\ )$$

Answer (score 2):

**First, show that this is true for $n=1$:**

$2^{2}\cdot3^{1}-1=11$

**Second, assume that this is true for $n$:**

$2^{2n}\cdot3^{n}-1=11k$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

$2^{2(n+1)}\cdot3^{n+1}-1=$

$\color\red{2^{2n}\cdot3^{n}-1}+11\cdot2^{2n}\cdot3^{n}=$

$\color\red{11k}+11\cdot2^{2n}\cdot3^{n}=$

$11(k+2^{2n}\cdot3^{n})$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.

Answer (score 0):

By the Binomial theorem,

$$12^n-1=(11+1)^n-1\\
=11^n+n\,11^{n-1}+\frac{n(n-1)}211^{n-2}+\cdots+\frac{n(n-1)}211^2+n\,11+1-1,$$

which is a multiple of $11$.